# Can I create azure cosmos db document with a custom key other than Id

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using azure cosmos db for saving and editing my session information. Currently i am not using ID in my document, instead i have another unique field with all docs. How can i update my query to get documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use whatever property you want, for your custom key (just make sure you don't remove its index). By default, all properties are indexed unless you explicitly set up a custom index policy that removes certain properties from being indexed.

You cannot eliminate the built-in id property though; if you don't set it explicitly, it will just be set to a guid.

If you are doing queries, this really shouldn't matter, functionality-wise. Just search on whatever properties you want. However: If you are doing point-reads (a read is more efficient, RU-wise, than a query, when retrieving a single document) you can only perform a point-read by specifying the `id` property, not your custom property. If you must use a custom property *and* you need to do point-reads, you can consider storing your custom property as `id` as well (as long as it's guaranteed to be unique per document).

Comment: i do like the suggestion of taking your unique field and use it as "id" in the document instead of letting the system generate a new id for you each time.

Comment: if you're not putting an "id" field in to your data, David is correct, one will be created for you, a new guid. So, becareful if you think you are updating an existing doc ... but it gets a new id, you might actually be creating new records instead of updating existing records, especially if you are using the "Upsert" / Create or Replace logic.